# Combinations of percentages.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, percentages

How would I calculate all possible combinations of given percentages so that none of the combinations is less than 51%? For example one such combination of

- 24%
- 23%
- 21%
- 17%
- 8%
- 7%

would be 23% + 24% + 7% = 54%.

Comment: with our without repetition? For example $7 /{%} + 7 /{%} + 8 /{%} $ ?

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut Without repetition, hence percentages.

Comment: @Paul 32% is less than 51% and therefore of no interest.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104247/173262) we can find what you want from the generating function of partitions without repetition based on $k$ numbers for $k\in \{7,8,17,21,23,24\}$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
SQ:=&(1+x^7)(1+x^8)(1+x^{17})(1+x^{21})(1+x^{23})(1+x^{24})\\
=&\,x^{100}+x^{93}+x^{92}+x^{85}+x^{83}+x^{79}+x^{77}\\
&+2x^{76}+x^{75}+x^{72}+x^{71}+x^{70}+2x^{69}+2x^{68}\\
&+x^{64}+2x^{62}+x^{61}+x^{60}+x^{59}+x^{56}+2x^{55}\\
&+x^{54}+2x^{53}+2x^{52}+x^{51}+x^{49}+2x^{48}+2x^{47}\\
&+x^{46}+2x^{45}+x^{44}+x^{41}+x^{40}+x^{39}+2x^{38}\\
&+x^{36}+2x^{32}+2x^{31}+x^{30}+x^{29}+x^{28}+x^{25}\\
&+2x^{24}+x^{23}+x^{21}+x^{17}+x^{15}+x^8+x^7+1
\end{align*}
$$

Now, from the previous expression, we must count the coefficients of the exponents that are equal or bigger to $51$, that is if we set

$$f(x):=x^{100}+x^{93}+x^{92}+x^{85}+x
   ^{83}+x^{79}+x^{77}+2
   x^{76}+x^{75}+x^{72}+x^{71}
   +x^{70}+2 x^{69}+2
   x^{68}+x^{64}+2
   x^{62}+x^{61}+x^{60}+x^{59}
   +x^{56}+2 x^{55}+x^{54}+2
   x^{53}+2
   x^{52}+x^{51}$$

then $f(1)$ is what you want.